# Can pydub know if a file has ever been played?

Tags: python, audio, pydub

I'm trying to create a python script to help me manage my car radio's music library. The idea is the following: I have a USB flash drive with 2-hour podcast mp3 files. Since I never drive such long journeys, the script splits the files in 5-minute fragments and removes the originals.

Now, the next thing I would want to do is automatically remove the ones I've already played. My first idea was something like DRM or a self-destructing file that erased itself once it's played, but from what I have found online that's pretty much impossible.

So, the question is, can I check with pydub if the file has been already played, so when I arrive home I can plug the USB in the computer, run the script, detect the played files and erase them?

Thanks and sorry if it's a dumb question!

Comment: To do that you would need to write to the file, in which case you could just delete it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Playing an audio file doesn't modify the file.

Unless your car stereo writes some sort of log to the flash drive of what it's played -- which is unlikely; I've never seen or heard of a stereo that did that -- there's no way to determine which files have been played.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I wanted to know.